# mysql - Return the row when insert fails due to duplicate key?

Tags: mysql, sql

When inserting multiple rows, is it possible to get the row that the insert statement fails on due to a duplicate key?

Comment: How many rows are you inserting?

Comment: Don't you have the key that caused the duplicate error in the logs?

Comment: I'm not sure that MySQL provides this level of granularity.  You could just do the inserts one at a time.

Comment: Why not just validate that insert is only possible when there is no duplicate key?

Comment: I'm inserting up to 100 rows or more. Isn't it faster if I perform a single insert statement instead of doing it one at a time? Also, what do u mean by the logs? I'm using php and I can't find any attribute in the mysqli class that would contain the key that caused the error

Comment: I can think of multiple ways, including a temporary table and "hackarounds" with session variables. Which one to use depends on your priorities, the envirement and what you want to do, if the insert fails. But you didn't provide enough information about your "problem".

Comment: If you provide a [mcve] demonstrating a ***small, simple example*** of how you're inserting the rows, it will go a long way providing a reference from which someone can answer your question. However, your question would likely already exist because there are already ***very many*** questions about finding duplicates in SQL on this site.

Comment: Something to note: There are 2 possible sources of your duplicates: **(1)** New data duplicates existing data. E.g. Target has `A,C,E` and you try to insert `D,E,F`. **(2)** The data you're trying to insert already has duplicates. E.g. Target has `A,C,E` and you try insert `D,F,D`.